# Fail to create kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Ran following command to create a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine. Then I got below error.

[Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) is green for GKE as of 10 AM July 22, 2020 (Eastern Daylight Savings Time).

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
gcloud container clusters create demo \
  --cluster-version latest \
  --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
  --num-nodes 4 \
  --zone us-east1-b
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) Operation [<Operation
 clusterConditions: [<StatusCondition
 message: "[CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2 to the constraint to use external IP with it.">, <StatusCondition
 message: "[CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4 to the constraint to use external IP with it.">, <StatusCondition
 message: "[CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx to the constraint to use external IP with it.">, <StatusCondition
 message: "[CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br to the constraint to use external IP with it.">, <StatusCondition
 message: "Not all instances running in IGM after 27.672242329s. Expect 4. Current errors: [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br to the constraint to use external IP with it.">]
 detail: "Not all instances running in IGM after 27.672242329s. Expect 4. Current errors: [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br to the constraint to use external IP with it."
 endTime: '2020-07-22T13:50:22.491208073Z'
 name: 'operation-1595425781652-ad5953b3'
 nodepoolConditions: []
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(CREATE_CLUSTER, 1)
 progress: <OperationProgress
 metrics: [<Metric
 intValue: 6
 name: 'CLUSTER_DEPLOYING'>, <Metric
 intValue: 6
 name: 'CLUSTER_DEPLOYING_TOTAL'>]
 stages: []>
 selfLink: 'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/230730309217/zones/us-east1-b/operations/operation-1595425781652-ad5953b3'
 startTime: '2020-07-22T13:49:41.652224299Z'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: "Not all instances running in IGM after 27.672242329s. Expect 4. Current errors: [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br to the constraint to use external IP with it."
 targetLink: 'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/230730309217/zones/us-east1-b/clusters/demo'
 zone: 'us-east1-b'>] finished with error: Not all instances running in IGM after 27.672242329s. Expect 4. Current errors: [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4fv2 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-4gr4 to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-f1fx to the constraint to use external IP with it.; [CONDITION_NOT_MET]: Instance 'gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br' creation failed: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 230730309217. Add instance projects/hipster-shop-277101/zones/us-east1-b/instances/gke-demo-default-pool-a53ea683-g4br to the constraint to use external IP with it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can create cluster with this command without any issue.

Your issue is casued by your [organization policy constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) applied to this project.

> constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess

You will need to reach your organization admins to provide you proper permissions.

**Home > IAM & Admin > Identity & Organization > Define proper permissions.**

Comment: Yes, the account is associated with my institution, and the project is within the institution. Also, I remembered that I have recently received an e-mail regarding this IAM policy updates. Creating cluster with my personal account works.

Comment: @TaegyunKim if this answered your question please accept this answer. Otherwise please provide more information to investigate further.